# mod_rewrite issue

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have some old files that need to point to new files - the old files are indexed from Google like this: `old%20file%20here.pdf` - because the last people doing the site left spaces in file names - but in my Rewrites they just aren't matching the old file to send to the new - does anyone know how to ignore the `%20` and redirect right?

My rewrite code here:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/old%file%20here.pdf$ http://www.domain.co.uk/new-file.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Its working fine for rest of redirects which are pages with normal URLs.

Comment: found the answer to this was \\[space]name instead of what i was doing which was \%20name hop this helps some one else!

Comment: Please post it as an answer and accept it -- other users who will facing similar issues may find the answer quicker if they will see accepted answer. thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer, this is it

[space]name (so should be \ name) instead of what i was doing which was \%20name

hope this helps any one else!